# Xamarin Android DownloadManager downloads file to 100%, then goes to Queued, and finally says download is Unsuccessful

Tags: android, spring, xamarin, android-download-manager, resume-download

I am trying to download file from Java Spring backend to my Xamarin Forms app. I am using native Android manager. When I start download, I see new file in Files, and soon it starts downloading, finally reaching 100%. Immediately after that, the file goes to Queued status. After some time, it says that download is unsuccessful.
When I read the status, reason code is 1008, which means ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME.
However, what there is to resume if download went to 100%?
This happens only on Android 9, I tried with both 7 and 8.1 and it works without any errors.

Xamarin code:

```
public long download(string url, string filePath, string token) {
        var manager = (Android.App.DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.DownloadService);
        var source = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
        var request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
        request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        //request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, source.LastPathSegment);

        request.AddRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.AddRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

        long downloadId = manager.Enqueue(request);

        return downloadId;
    }
```

Java backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/download/{idBook}/{idDevice}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void download(@PathVariable int idBook, @PathVariable String idDevice, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception     
{
    String rangestring = request.getHeader("Range");
    //System.out.println(rangestring);
    if(rangestring != null)
    {
        String[] strings = (rangestring.substring(6)).split("-");
    }
    
    Book book = myBookRepository.getOne(idBook);
    
    String fileName = fileUtil.getFilePath(idBook);
    
    MultipartFileSender.fromFile(new File(fileName))
            .with(request)
            .with(response)
            .serveResource();
}
```

And MultipartFileSender is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4)